# In CodeIgniter, how do I access one model from within another?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Say I am in the delete_user() function in the user model, and I want it to use the delete_comment() function in my comment model.

I could access the comment tables directly, or load and call the other model from my controller, but to keep my code as abstract as possible I want to be able to access one model from within another.

Is this possible with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need this:

```
class User_model extends Model
{
    function get_something()
    {
         $CI =& get_instance();
         $CI->load->model('profile_model');
         return $CI->profile_model->get_another_thing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access it like you can in a controller given it's already loaded.

```
$this->some_other_model->method();
```

Comment: Are you sure? This does not work for me. Moved the code from my model to controller, and it worked.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Providing you have loaded both models for use, you should be able to call your delete user method, followed by your delete comment method. Having said that - I don't know that this is the correct design.
Given that when you delete a user you always need to delete your comments, this probably sits better in your model. Can you post your full model code, for delete users and delete comments

Comment: I loaded the comment model within my user model, right before I tried calling the function. PHP doesn't seem to have a problem with loading the file, but if I try the function my page doesn't render.

Comment: Why the downvote on this answer? @Yorick Peterse
is right as long as the model is loaded which is what he said.

Comment: Note that if you are using Codeigniter 2 you might need to add a __get method to your model in order to be able to access other models, libraries, etc. More information on this topic can be found here: http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_2.0_-_now_with_more_awesome/

Answer (score 0):

```
   function model_load_model($model_name)
   {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $CI->load->model($model_name);
      return $CI->$model_name;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to load your model like this:

```
$this->load->model('comment_model');
$this->comment_model->delete_comment($userId);
```