# How to instantiate a Model class to another Model class that has a parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to instantiate a Model class to another Model class that has a parameter in codeigniter.

Account class:

```
    class Account extends CI_Model 
    {
         $username;
         $password;
         public function __construct($username,$password);
         {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->username=$username;
            $this->password=$password;
         }

         function login()
         {
            $result=$this->db->query("SELECT username FROM account where username='$this->$username' and password='$this->password'");
            return $result->row(1);
         }
    }
```

TestAccount Class:

```
 class TestAccount extends CI_Model 
 {
        function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->library('unit_test');
                $this->load->model('account','',TRUE);
        }

        /* In this test, the valid values of the credentials are the following:
         * Username: myUsername
         * Password: myPassword
         */

        function testCorrectCredentials()
        {
            $anAccount=new $account("myUsername","myPassword");
            $result = $anAccount->login();
            $test_res = ($result > 0); // matches content, the return value is the id
            $expected_result = true;
            $test_name = "Given the correct credentials(username and password exists in database), this function will be able to retrieve the league manager username";
            $this->unit->run($test_res, $expected_result, $test_name); 
        }
}
```

I want to instantiate my Account class, but how?

Comment: Instead of `$anAccount=new $account("myUsername","myPassword");`, you can use `$this->account->function_name("myUsername","myPassword")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [In CodeIgniter, how do I access one model from within another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646188/in-codeigniter-how-do-i-access-one-model-from-within-another)

Comment: yeah, I appreciate your answer, but is it impossible to instantiate a class in codeigniter? because im trying to make it OOP approach.

Comment: This is also OOPS approach but in CI method.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a model the file it is within is automatically included which means you don't have to access it solely through, in your case, $account you can simply do

```
$anAccount = new Account("myUsername","myPassword");
```